# android- How to get borders like this

Tags: android, android-drawable, android-styles

This is the edittext I want to have:

[image]

This is what I got so far:

[image]

Two issues:

1. as you can see, the top border should be much smaller.
2. I set padding on the code, but it didn't work an as you can see. The text is at top of the edittext. How can I make it align center and in the middle of edittext?

This is my drawable xml:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<shape xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:padding="15dp"
    android:shape="rectangle" >

    <solid android:color="#3C1251" />

    <corners
        android:bottomLeftRadius="5dp"
        android:bottomRightRadius="5dp"
        android:topLeftRadius="5dp"
        android:topRightRadius="5dp" />

    <stroke
            android:width="2.3dp"
            android:color="#56DEF1" />

</shape>
```

Comment: Use a **9 patch**: http://radleymarx.com/blog/simple-guide-to-9-patch/

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To reduce the size of the top border, you might try using an `inset` to shift the entire drawable up by a pixel or two.

[image]

For example, for a 1dp top border you might set the stroke width to 3, and the insetTop to -2.

```
<inset xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:insetTop="-2dp">

    <shape
        android:padding="15dp"
        android:shape="rectangle" >

        <solid android:color="#3C1251" />

        <corners
            android:bottomLeftRadius="5dp"
            android:bottomRightRadius="5dp"
            android:topLeftRadius="5dp"
            android:topRightRadius="5dp" />

        <stroke
            android:width="3dp"
            android:color="#56DEF1" />
    </shape>
</inset>
```

To align the text to the center, try setting `android:gravity` on the EditText to `center`. 
To put "padding" around the edge of the border, try setting a `layout_margin`.

```
<EditText
    ...
    android:background="@drawable/ourDrawable"
    android:text="text goes here"
    android:gravity="center"
    android:layout_margin="5dp" />
```